# Integrals: Find the area of the region.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Find the area of the region in the first quadrant bounded by $y=x^2$, $y=4x^2$, and $y=2$.

The answer given is $\frac{2}{3} \sqrt2$ but I have no idea what this question is asking.

I'm used to questions like finding the area of one function under an integral $[a,b]$.

Would someone please explain?

Answer (score 8):

Draw the graph for all 3 equations. Find the intersection of the 3 equations. When you draw the equations you will also find the bounds of the integral. Let's solve for 2 for each equation. y=2 says that its the whole area under 2 between 0 and 2. Next we look at x^2 and solve the equation that satisfies the condition x<2. so we find that sqrt(2) satisfies the equation x^2<=2. Next we look at 4x^2 and set that equal to 2 also. we find that 
x<(2/sqrt(2)) satisfies this condition so the bounds are from sqrt(2)/2 to sqrt(2). Looking at the graph we can see that anything under the curve x^2 satisfies all 3 conditions so you integrate from [sqrt(2)/2,2] by x^2. You should be able to get 2/3 of sqrt(2) after your calculations.

Answer (score 5):

Let's draw a simple plot of the curves and enclosing line $y=2$:

[image]

Considering  the first quadrant, we see that the easier way to do the area is to consider $y$ as independent variable. So we have: $$\int_0^2dy\int_{x=\sqrt{y}/2}^{\sqrt{y}}dx$$

Comment: @B.S.: Nice graphics! =1